# yet another django url redirection issue

Tags: python, html, django, url, redirect

The following view is supposed to load a page, 'learn.html', but it simply returns to the index for some reason.

```
def learn(request):

    try:

    ...  # everything goes smoothly here, the else clause is evaluated.

    else:
        return render(request, 'associate/learn.html', {'dataset':model, 'ordered_groups':ordered_groups})
```

Here are my urls:

**images\urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^images/', include('images_app.urls', namespace="images_app")),
    url(r'^associate/', include('associate.urls', namespace="associate")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**associate\urls.py**   EDIT :  I accidentally wrote images\urls.py - corrected now.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^learn/', "associate.views.learn", name='learn'),
    url(r'^$', "associate.views.index", name='index'),
)
```

This is the index page that loads fine, from where the user should should be redirected to learn.html by clicking the learn button.  However, the index page just reloads.

**associate\index.html**

```
Choose a dataset 

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'associate:learn' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for dataset in datasets %}
    <input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ dataset.id }}" />
    <label for="dataset{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ dataset }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="learn" />
</form>
```

**associate\learn.html**

```
THIS IS THE LEARN PAGE
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For urls.py of associate app try this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('associate',
  url(r'^learn/', "associate.views.learn", name='learn'),
  url(r'^$', "associate.views.index", name='index'),
)
```

Comment: I added the 'associate' and I get the error "  ImportError at /associate/learn/
No module named associate" Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: associate should be in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: +Özgür Eroğlu  I do have associate in my installed_apps section.  not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Ok please try it as following.
    - Replace  url(r'^associate/', include('associate.urls', namespace="associate"))  with  url(r'^associate/', include('associate.urls'))
    - Replace url(r'^learn/', "associate.views.learn", name='learn') with url(r'^learn/', associate.views.learn)

Comment: +Özgür Eroğlu  Just tried your suggestion, I get the same error :(  Thanks for your help though!.